# How to get values through connected tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such a question. I got two tables, the first one contains comments, and the second id comments and album id to which the comment was left

```
> CREATE TABLE `review` (`id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
>   `user_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,`comment` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )


> CREATE TABLE `review_album` (`review_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
> `album_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`,
> `album_id`),  INDEX `review_album_review_idx` (`review_id`) )
```

I tried this way:

```
SELECT * from review_album JOIN review WHERE album_id = '300001'
```

But i got result two times.

How can I get comment text for a specific album_id?

Comment: Normally you would JOIN ON something without the ON clause you get a cross join/cartesian product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general syntax is:

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name1 JOIN table-name2 
    ON column-name1 = column-name2
 WHERE condition
```

The general syntax with INNER is:

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name1 INNER JOIN table-name2 
    ON column-name1 = column-name2
 WHERE condition
```

Note: The INNER keyword is optional: it is the default as well as the most commonly used JOIN operation.

Refrence : https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join

Answer (score 2):

Try with **InnerJoin**

```
SELECT *
FROM review_album
JOIN review ON review_album.review_id=review.id
WHERE album_id = '300001'
```

**[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)**

Answer (score 1):

you have forgotten the on condition, everytime you have a join you'd better specify the condition of join, otherwais you have every connection available.
Hovewer the solution

```
SELECT * 
FROM review_album RA 
JOIN review R ON RA.column_fk = R.column_fk 
WHERE album_id = '300001'
```

Here the documentation for join https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: The join without type is interpreted like inner join, but if you want use the inner join is better write inner join becaus it's more clear, however if you want another management of null you chan choise left outer join, right outer join or full outer yoin.
I think you can find everything in the documentation that I passed in my reply

Answer (score 1):

```
    try using this :



SELECT *
    FROM review_album  ra
    JOIN review r ON rareview_id=r.id
    WHERE album_id = '300001'
```